# Calendar shows on icon as well as inline calendar from input box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery,
I want to display calender,if cursor place on textbox and cursor place on calender icon both.
My code is below:-

```
$(".dob1").datepicker({
    hideIfNoPrevNext : true,
    yearRange : "-95",
    showOn : "button",
    buttonImage : rootPath + "images/callender-icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly : true,
    changeMonth : true,
    changeYear : true,
    maxDate : '-18Y',
    dateFormat : "mm/dd/yy",
    buttonText : "Choose date of birth",
    inline : true

});
```

please give answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Correction : you are using jQuery AND jQuery UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In showOn, instead of "button" use "both"

```
$(".dob1").datepicker({
    hideIfNoPrevNext : true,
    yearRange : "-95",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage : rootPath + "images/callender-icon.png",
    buttonImageOnly : true,
    changeMonth : true,
    changeYear : true,
    maxDate : '-18Y',
    dateFormat : "mm/dd/yy",
    buttonText : "Choose date of birth",
    inline : true

});
```